# Can't cope with inheritance

Tags: java

I have (some pseudocode):

```
public class Thrd extends Thread{

    protected void letUsFinalize(){
        int a = 0; // Just for debugging.     
    }
}

public class FreeThread extends Thrd{

    @Override
    protected void letUsFinalize() {
        FreeThread.this.interrupt();
    }

}
```

Please, have a look at the picture. Our object now is of class FreeThread (visible in the Variables subsection). So, I come to the upper break point in the picture, press Step into and I occur at the lower break point. I mean that I occur in the method of the class Thrd (superclass).

What should I do so that the method of subclass would execute in this case?

[image]

Comment: Don't extend `Thread` unless you _really_ know what you are doing.

Comment: Did you instantiate `FreeThread` or `Thrd`?

Comment: @Andreas, FreeThread. Anyway, we can see that "this" is now an instance of FreeThread.

Comment: do you mean add super.letUsFinilize() in FreeThread?

Comment: I think he's saying that the super is what is being called and that's not what he wants.

Comment: I want FreeThread(subclass) to call its own method (that of the subclass).

Comment: Question for you: are Thrd and FreeThread in different packages?

Comment: @theSilentOne, No, they are in the same package.

Comment: The way inheritance works in Java dictates that the overridden method in the subclass is called, regardless of where it gets called. If you are getting a differently result, show us a complete code example that reproduces it. Otherwise it's impossible to say what's going on except it must be some other factor. [Here is a simple example that shows the method is dispatched dynamically.](http://ideone.com/wS7eqG)

Comment: Well, I don't know why but NetBeans seems to ignore step into. If I put a break point in the method of the subclass, the debugger steps into perfectly (in the subclass). Why it should be like this I donn't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the object that you are using is an instance of FreeThread, then calling object.letUsFinalise() will call the method from FreeThread.

It looks like you are calling letUsFinalise() from the super class, so it's not possible to call the subclass' method unless you are using a static object to it (demonstrated below).

```
public class SuperClass {

    public void method(){
        Objects.object.method();
    }

}

class SubClass extends SuperClass{

    @Override
    public void method(){
        System.out.println("I'm the sub class!");
    }

}

class Objects{

    public static SubClass object = new SubClass();
}
```

I suggest that you create a static object of FreeThread and use that to call the method, as shown above.